# TextView Background Image not resizing with respect to text

Tags: android, textview

i have a textview and i have set its background of a image. The image is not resizing with respect to the text.

For example :- if my text is "**A**", the background is still the same and not resizing to fit the text. Here is the xml for textview :-

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/navmenusection_right_label_action"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:background="@drawable/textview_round_background"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:text="A"
    android:textColor="#fff"
    android:textSize="13sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"/>
```

[image]

Comment: why aren't u using 9Patch Graphics? This is meant to be the background of resizeable Views, keep in mind that 9 patch aren't going smaller just bigger so draw a minimum size http://developer.android.com/tools/help/draw9patch.html

Comment: Are you using 9Patch? And if yes, do you also set the padding lines for the image? Because that can be your problem..

Comment: the background is going to stretch but not shrink. use a 9patch of the smallest size . or if you don't wanna go for a 9patch go for a smaller version of the background.

Comment: http://postimg.org/image/lqxnbt747/ . This is the image. Can anyone create a small nine patch for it as i don;t know how to do it

Answer (score 1):

now I really understand your Problem.
Android is not downsizing Image Backgrounds. In your example the Background is the width-giver.

For you purpose just draw a 9 Patch Image where you can declare the regions which are stretched (try to only mark the not rounded regions for a better result) and where your content should be displayed.

Google has a quite good DOC out there:
[Documentation](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/draw9patch.html)

keep in mind that 9 Patch images are only stretched and are not getting downscaled so I would use only a minimum width Picture. Just do it like this and make it a 9Patch

[PIC EXAMPLE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W9UZr.png)

Comment: How did you created this image ? . I used your image and got this result. It is not resizing correctly. It is coming in oval shape. http://postimg.org/image/rkdwlqq8x/  . Actually i don;t know how to create a nine patch image

Comment: so please have a look at the Documentation, link above, android sdk comes with a 9Patch drawing software

Comment: I have not yet solved it. It is not working correctly. Image is not expanding correctly. Can you create a nine patch for the above image ? It should have round corners like above only even if the text is a single characters or 20 characters

Comment: Hey cmon, make it on your own! It is no hustle and no magic, have a look at the docu or search it on youtube!

Comment: Ya I made it my own from draw9patch.com

Answer (score 1):

use 9 patch image or create your own xml layout of this type

create bg.xml in drawable folder ans set to your text background

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item android:left="1dp" android:right="1dp" android:top="1dp" android:bottom="1dp">
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="#000000" />
            <stroke
                android:width="1.2dp"
                android:color="#000000" />
            <corners android:radius="15dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

Comment: This won;t help. I have tried. See the image above. See the rounded effects and it is not a flat image and i don't know how to create a 9 patch image. Can you create it ? Please post it. Thanks